# Does it matter where I place the tiles when expanding my guild?

Tags: guild-of-dungeoneering

When expanding the guild in *Guild of Dungeoneering* you can choose where you want to place for example the different kinds of barracks for your different dungeoneers.

Is there any importance as to where you place them? Do they for example influence each other in any way or can I just randomly place them when expanding my guild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, No.  There is no importance in the placement of Guild Rooms.

That said, I sometimes click on the Grave Yard or the Trophy Room to see their contents.  As such, I place them so they are available without scrolling.